# .htaccess redirect with underscore letter

Tags: .htaccess

My current .htaccess file is below:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule .* https://www.tuitionathome.my%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]

RewriteEngine on
Options -Indexes
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php55 .php .php5 .php4 .php3

RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9]+)$ http://www.tuitionathome.my/inc/go.php?webname=$1 [R=301,L]
```

> [image: img]

Comment: the attached file is here: http://i.stack.imgur.com/HqMI7.png

Comment: w0w, screenshot of question :o so meta

Comment: Why the redirection to `https` at all?

Comment: It fails because your regex doesn't include an `_` in the rules. You need to change it from `([A-Za-z0-9]+)` to `([A-Za-z0-9_]+)` better yet, I would just use `([\w]+)`

Comment: @PanamaJack - Thanks! Your solution works. I used ([A-Za-z0-9_]+). By the way is ([\w]+) the equivalent of ([A-Za-z0-9_]+) ?

Comment: @hjpotter92 - screenshot is because as a newbie, I couldn't comment with more than 2 hyperlinks :P

Comment: @hjpotter92 - is redirection to https redundant?

Comment: @JohnL yes I know that. That's why I suggested using `([\w]+)` because it's shorthand and you can't really make a mistake leaving something out. Also yes does not seem right. Because you are redirecting to https and then back to http. How are you not getting a redirect loop?

Comment: Just `(\w+)` is fine. Character set is redundant as well here. As for the https redirection, read the above comment by @PanamaJack

Comment: @PanamaJack  - How shall I change my htaccess to make right the redirection issue? Could you please tell me what do I need to edit / remove? Thanks

Comment: @hjpotter92 - How shall I change my htaccess to make right the redirection issue? Could you please tell me what do I need to edit / remove? Thanks